# Webpack 5 + React Router v6 - Blank Page on Build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom, webpack-5

For some reason, when I use `npm run serve`, I can access my page just fine and the routes work as they are supposed to. However, when I use `npm run build`, I encounter a white screen even if I correct my asset directories. What am I doing wrong?

```js
// App.tsx
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Application entry point.
 *
 * @return {JSX.Element}
 */
const App: () => JSX.Element = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>Hello world!</h1>} />
        <Route path="/add" element={<h1>Hello add!</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I created a breakaway branch to isolate the issue and leave out any unnecessary code: https://bitbucket.org/blackboardd/shoppy/src/breakaway-for-router/.

If anyone wants to try running it:

```sh
git clone -b breakaway-for-router git@bitbucket.org:blackboardd/shoppy.git
cd shoppy
npm install

// This works fine.
npm run serve

// This has a blank white screen when the index.html file is opened, even with the asset directories corrected for local viewing.
npm run build
```

System Information:
Visual Studio Code on Remote WSL 2
Windows 11 Version 21H2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two issues.

**Problem #1: Bad production build testing.**

I should have been testing it with a web server. What I ended up using was a globally installed `serve` package and running `serve -s dist`. This ended up giving me working routes. The only thing I modified about my TypeScript files was importing `Route` and `Routes` from `react-router-dom` where I was previously importing them from `react-router`, but I'm not sure if that had any meaningful effect.

So one of the things I made sure to do was add this line into my `webpack.prod.js` file:

```js
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
  },
```

**Problem #2: 404 error on routes other than `/`.**

then I was having an issue with my redirects. I needed a `_redirects` file in my distribution:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

I also used the `copy-webpack-plugin` to move the file from `public` to `dist`. This is the snippet for that portion:

```js
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'public/_redirects',
          to: '.',
        },
      ],
    })
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

In case, you are using Webpack (v5) to bundle files, you will encounter another problem that says "Cannot GET /add", when you navigate to this route in the browser (like http://127.0.0.1:5000/add).

The simple solution for this is to add a property to your devServer in the webpack.config.js file with the name of historyApiFallback and set it to true.
Like this:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 5000,
        historyApiFallback: true,   //for react router
    },
};
```

Credits: https://blog.jimmydc.com/webpack-history-api-fallback/

Answer (score 0):

add this to your package.json file `"homepage": "/"`

EDIT: `"homepage": "./"` works

Comment: Hmm. I just tried that, and it didn't do anything. Did you try this with my branch after cloning it?

Comment: EDIT: try with "homepage": "./"